# using eloquent model property in subquery of with function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

My question may be confuse because I've started learning Laravel.

Can I use eloquent model property in subquery of with() function?

I have `classes`, `students`, and `grades` tables. I wish to get

```
$classes = [{id:1, name:'maths', students:[{id:2, name: john,
grade:B},{id:1, name: Mac, grade:C}]}, {id:2, name:'physics',
students:[{id:2, name: john, grade:null},{id:1, name: Mac,
grade:null}]}]
```

for example:

```
        $classes = Class::with(['students' => function($query){ 
        ->leftJoin('grades', 'grades.student_id', '=', 'students.id')
        }])->get()->toJSON();
```

This query doesn't select correct grades of related classes. I wish to use `class::id = grades.class_id` in join condition.

I use leftJoin because some class may not have released its grade.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it this way:

```
 $classes = Class::with(['students' => function($query){ 
        ->leftJoin('grades', function($join) {
             $join->on('grades.student_id', '=', 'students.id');
             $join->on('grades.class_id', '=', 'class.id');
          })
        }])->get()->toJSON();
```

Comment: Hi Marcin, thank for your help, but I aldy tried it. It result this error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: class.id`

Comment: @RyanExlay It should probably be `classes.id` (or whatever your table name for the Class model is)

Comment: @lukasgeiter, same error landed. Anyway, thank for your help. I can't call  class property in students. I am trying to use hasManyThrough relations student->class->grade relations.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solutions, even though, not best solution but it worked. Thank @Marcin Nabialek and @lukasgeiter. It is just simply to through pivot table `class_student`.

```
 $classes = Class::with(['students' => function($query){ 
        $query->leftJoin('grades', function($join) {
             $join->on('grades.student_id', '=', 'students.id');
             $join->on('students.id', '=', 'class_student.student_id');
             $join->on('class_student.class_id', '=', 'grades.class_id');
          })
        }])->get()->toJSON();
```

It took too much time bcoz passing through many join tables.

Hoping to get better solutions.